# AngularJS ng-repeat columns

Tags: angularjs

I got two divs with classes col-left and col-right.

how can i achieve the following using ng-repeat

```
<span ng-repeat="value in items">
<div>
   <div class='col-left'>{{val.content}}</div>
   <div class='col-right'>{{val.content}}</div> 
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: the question is not clear for me. what do you want to achieve with col-left and col-right using ng-repeat

Comment: Sorry mate will try to explain more next time, the answer below works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the better way

```
<span ng-repeat="value in items track by $index">
    <div class="{'col-left':$odd, 'col-right':$even}">{{value.content}}</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-repeat="value in items track by $index">
<div>
   <div class="col-left" ng-if="$index % 2 != 0">{{value.content}}</div>
   <div class="col-right" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">{{value.content}}</div> 
</div>
</span>
```

Or :

```
<span ng-repeat="value in items track by $index">
        <div>
           <div ng-class-odd="'col-left'" ng-class-even="'col-right'">
               {{value.content}}
           </div>
        </div>
   </span>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You could use `$even` and `$odd` for this, [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)